# Compilation failure after adding Lombok NonNull annotation to JDO Entity fields

Tags: java, lombok, datanucleus, isis, isis2

Based on the Apache Isis 2 SimpleApp JDO project (https://github.com/apache/isis-app-simpleapp/tree/jdo) I tried to slightly modify the `SimpleObject` class to mark some fields (`name` and `notes`) as not nullable using the Lombok annotation `@NonNull`. This unexpectedly results in a compilation failure

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project simpleapp-jdo-module-simple: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
Error:  /home/runner/work/isis-app-simpleapp/isis-app-simpleapp/module-simple/target/generated-sources/annotations/domainapp/modules/simple/dom/so/QSimpleObject.java:[35,51] cannot find symbol
Error:    symbol:   class java
Error:    location: class domainapp.modules.simple.dom.so.QSimpleObject
Error:  /home/runner/work/isis-app-simpleapp/isis-app-simpleapp/module-simple/target/generated-sources/annotations/domainapp/modules/simple/dom/so/QSimpleObject.java:[36,51] cannot find symbol
Error:    symbol:   class java
Error:    location: class domainapp.modules.simple.dom.so.QSimpleObject
Error:  -> [Help 1]
```

Related GitHub Action: https://github.com/a-st/isis-app-simpleapp/runs/5330590432

The DataNucleus generated class `isis-app-simpleapp/module-simple/target/generated-sources/annotations/domainapp/modules/simple/dom/so/QSimpleObject.java` looks like this

```java
package domainapp.modules.simple.dom.so;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.jdo.query.*;
import org.datanucleus.api.jdo.query.*;

@Generated(value="org.datanucleus.jdo.query.JDOQueryProcessor")
public class QSimpleObject extends PersistableExpressionImpl<SimpleObject> implements PersistableExpression<SimpleObject>
{
    public static final QSimpleObject jdoCandidate = candidate("this");

    public static QSimpleObject candidate(String name)
    {
        return new QSimpleObject(null, name, 5);
    }

    public static QSimpleObject candidate()
    {
        return jdoCandidate;
    }

    public static QSimpleObject parameter(String name)
    {
        return new QSimpleObject(SimpleObject.class, name, ExpressionType.PARAMETER);
    }

    public static QSimpleObject variable(String name)
    {
        return new QSimpleObject(SimpleObject.class, name, ExpressionType.VARIABLE);
    }

    public final ObjectExpression<org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService> repositoryService;
    public final ObjectExpression<org.apache.isis.applib.services.title.TitleService> titleService;
    public final ObjectExpression<org.apache.isis.applib.services.message.MessageService> messageService;
    public final ObjectExpression<@lombok.NonNull java.lang.String> name;
    public final ObjectExpression<@lombok.NonNull java.lang.String> notes;

    public QSimpleObject(PersistableExpression parent, String name, int depth)
    {
        super(parent, name);
        this.repositoryService = new ObjectExpressionImpl<org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService>(this, "repositoryService");
        this.titleService = new ObjectExpressionImpl<org.apache.isis.applib.services.title.TitleService>(this, "titleService");
        this.messageService = new ObjectExpressionImpl<org.apache.isis.applib.services.message.MessageService>(this, "messageService");
        this.name = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "name");
        this.notes = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "notes");
    }

    public QSimpleObject(Class type, String name, ExpressionType exprType)
    {
        super(type, name, exprType);
        this.repositoryService = new ObjectExpressionImpl<org.apache.isis.applib.services.repository.RepositoryService>(this, "repositoryService");
        this.titleService = new ObjectExpressionImpl<org.apache.isis.applib.services.title.TitleService>(this, "titleService");
        this.messageService = new ObjectExpressionImpl<org.apache.isis.applib.services.message.MessageService>(this, "messageService");
        this.name = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "name");
        this.notes = new StringExpressionImpl(this, "notes");
    }
}
```

According to Visual Studio Code the following lines are causing issues (`Illegally placed annotation: type annotations must directly precede the simple name of the type they are meant to affect (or the [] for arrays)Java(1610613796)`)

```java
    public final ObjectExpression<@lombok.NonNull java.lang.String> name;
    public final ObjectExpression<@lombok.NonNull java.lang.String> notes;
```

[image]

The source code is located at https://github.com/a-st/isis-app-simpleapp/tree/jdo-lombok-nonnull

Answer (score 2):

Issue seems to be related to https://github.com/datanucleus/datanucleus-jdo-query/issues/18 and is solved with specifying

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-jdo-query</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-m1</version>
        </dependency>
```